# Search over multicore index without same schema solr

Tags: search, solr, distributed, multicore

I use Solr, and i would like to know if i can search over multiple index using multicore. I know there is "Distributed Search" but i think it's only for index with same schema.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no we can search with different schema also but only thing is it will  search in common field..[See this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124657/calling-solr-inside-solr)  .

Further for manipulation we can use solrj. else if only in solr .. read about ***Core Admin Handler***
let me know  if you need any help further.